# reactjs higher-order composition with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript1.6

I have a base class for all my components that has an initialize function that i don't want to repeat throughout all the components.  This is in a separate package that i linked from another project.

```
import React = require('react/addons');
abstract class BaseAppComponent<P, S> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props?: P, context?: any) {
       super(props, context);
    }
    protected _initialize() {
        ...
    }
}
export = BaseAppComponent;
```

My app uses it like so

```
import React = require('react/addons');
import MyLib = require('mylib');
class MyApp extends MyLib.BaseAppComponent<AppProps, AppState> {
   constructor(props: AppProps, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
   },
   componentWillMount() {
     this._initialize();
   },
   render() {
      return (<MyAppComponents />);
   }
}

export = MyApp;
```

My problem now is that i have a higher-order composition that i want to wrap MyApp around but i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

i've attempted.  This file is inside the MyLib project.

```
import React = require('react/addons');
function wrapInAppContainer(AppComponent: any) {
    return (props: any) => {
        return (
            <MyWrapper>
                <AppComponent {...props} />
            </MyWrapper>
        );
    };
}
export = wrapInAppContainer;
```

And so inside MyApp, i added at the end instead of export = MyApp, i did

```
export = MyLib.wrapInAppContainer(MyApp);
```

And inside my app.js file, i render the app

```
import React = require('react');
import MyApp = require('./components/<MyApp');

React.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('myapp'));
```

But when i run it, i get "Can't add property context, object is not extensible" errors.

What am i doing wrong?